# struggling to walk through php array element in recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am using recursive function to walk through array elements.But failed to get correct counter.What i did.

```
$i = 0 ;
$this->make_items($items,$i);
public function make_items($items,$i)
{
    foreach($items as $item){
        $i++;
        echo  '<position>'.$i.'</position>';    
        if(count($item['children'])){
                $this->make_items($item['children'],$i);
        }
}
```

But for array structure like

```
arr1
arr2
    arr3
        arr4
   arr5
arr6
```

Output of my code is

```
<postion>1</position>
<postion>2</position>
<postion>3</position>
<postion>4</position>
<postion>4</position>
<postion>3</position>
```

While i needed

```
<postion>1</position>
<postion>2</position>
<postion>3</position>
<postion>4</position>
<postion>5</position>
<postion>6</position>
```

What i am doing wrong or what i understood wrong about recursion.
If there is better way to do this then please advice.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$i` changes only in the function and it doesn't affect variable outside of the function. When it's recursion, then it seems that it is in one function, but new variable `$i` is created for each call.

The simplest solution is pass value by reference. It's done by adding `&` before parameter `$i` in definition of function:

```
public function make_items($items,&$i) { /* the rest of code remains same*/ }
```

Second solution returning value of `$i` and assigning it as new value outside of called function:

```
$i = 0 ;
$this->make_items($items,$i); //now $i is still 0 but return value is 6

public function make_items($items,$i)
{
    foreach($items as $item){
        $i++;
        echo  '<position>'.$i.'</position>';    
        if(count($item['children'])){
                $i = $this->make_items($item['children'],$i); // assign new value of $i
        }
    return $i; // return actual value of $i
}
```

Comment: `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: thanks for the short explanation .It worked I understood my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if (count($item))` to `if (is_array($item))`